# Rest api call fails in POST API call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, swagger-ui

Hi I have newly created a microservice post API call with STS4 which was build and deployed successfully. the localhost:8080/demo/ link is opening up. but the rest maping underneath it failing with 404 not found. I haved added requestmapping and post mapping and tried still not working. Can anyone fix the code?

PFB the code:-
POM:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip> true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

here is the config for swagger :-

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration  
//Enable Swagger  
@EnableSwagger2 
public class SwaggerConfig {
  
  @Bean  
  public Docket api() {  
     //creating constructor of Docket class that accepts parameter DocumentationType  
     return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);  
  }
}
```

here is the rest controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.demo.model.MyResponse;
import com.example.demo.service.dao.DemoServiceDAO;
import com.example.demo.service.impl.DemoServiceImpl;

@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value ="/newcall", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class DemoController {
  Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoController.class);
  
  @PostMapping(value ="/newResp", headers ="Accept=Application/JSON", produces="Application/JSON")
  public MyResponse newResp(@RequestBody String myInput) {
    MyResponse myResponse = null;
    try {
      DemoServiceDAO demoServiceDAO = new DemoServiceImpl();
      logger.debug("Started getValue() method...");
      myResponse=demoServiceDAO.getValue(myInput);
      logger.debug("Completed getValue() method...");
      
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      logger.debug("Exception occurs",e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Exception occurs");
    }       
    return myResponse;
  }
}
```

here is the application:-

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.*")
@EnableSwagger2
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

here is the app.properties:-

```
    logging.file.name=opt/var/logs/demoService.log
    logging.file.path=opt/var/logs
    logging.level.web=DEBUG
    spring.jmx.default-domain=demo
    server.servlet.context-path=/demo
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
    management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
    
    springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url=true
    management.endpoint.info.enabled: true
    springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.enabled=true
    springfox.documentation.open-api.enabled=true
    spring.security.user.name = user
    spring.security.user.password = password
```

Output from `http://localhost:8080/demo/`

```
     "_links" : {
       "profile" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/demo/profile"
        }
     }
```

full code is in github with logs:-

https://github.com/Sourav654/tempProject/tree/master/demo

Comment: You don't really need the `ComponentScan` annotation there when using SpringBootApplication annotation. `SpringBootApplication` is equivalent to using @Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Without any logs we can only guess, but looking at your Controller I see some weird things. Can you please try the following?

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("newcall")
public class DemoController {
  Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoController.class);
  
  @PostMapping("/newResp", consumes = "application/json", produces = application/json)
  public MyResponse newResp(@RequestBody String myInput) {
    MyResponse myResponse = null;
    try {
      DemoServiceDAO demoServiceDAO = new DemoServiceImpl();
      logger.debug("Started getValue() method...");
      myResponse=demoServiceDAO.getValue(myInput);
      logger.debug("Completed getValue() method...");
      
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      logger.debug("Exception occurs",e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Exception occurs");
    }       
    return myResponse;
  }
}
```

Comment: no its still not working. I have uploaded my code in git...you can download full logs from here  https://github.com/Sourav654/tempProject/tree/master/demo